# VS code core command for output

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Does a VS code have a **core** command to write to the Output section?

For instance, there are the commands `cursorLeftSelect`, `editor.action.clipboardCutAction`, `cursorRight`, `editor.action.clipboardPasteAction`, and, of course, the `type` command to type. Is there a command to write to output?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, look at the `window.createOutputChannel("find-and-transform");` command.  You can put anything you want where the `find-and-transform` appears above.

```js
yourOutputChannel.appendLine(`\n${ jsOPError.stack }\n`);
yourOutputChannel.show(false);  // the false here will focus the output panel and this outputChannel within it
```

Comment: thanks @mark. I figured up to the `createOutputChannel` but I am modifying `settings.json` so I was looking to create the channel purely with the vs code commands

Comment: I am pretty sure the only way to write to an outputChannel is to create one yourself and then write to it and show it.  There is no simple executeCommand route to do it.  If you look through the `Keyboard Shortcuts` there is no command for writing to an outChannel.